# how does A'B'C' convert to A'+B'+C'?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to learning boolean algebra.
One of de morgan's law is not understood.
how does A'B'C' convert to A'+B'+C'?

As I know,
1. (A'B')' = A+B
2. (AB)'=A'+B'
3. (A+B)'=A'B'
I think it should be (A+B+C)'.

Is this same between A'+B'+C' and (A+B+C)' or A'B'C' and (ABC)'?

http://www.indiabix.com/digital-electronics/boolean-algebra-and-logic-simplification/discussion-138

Comment: Just make a big [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#binary_operations), once you see it for yourself it will be totally clear. Play around with different statements, you will learn it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post, you say:

```
2. (AB)'=A'+B' 
3. (A+B)'=A'B'
I think it should be (A+B+C)'.  <== I don't know where this fits in
```

then you provide four combinations:

```
A'+B'+C' and (A+B+C)' or A'B'C' and (ABC)'
```

Looking at each one,

```
A'+B'+C' = (ABC)'     (flipping 2 around and extending to three terms)
(A+B+C)' = A'B'C'     (from 3, extending to three terms)
A'B'C' = (A+B+C)'     (flipping 3 around and extending to three terms)
(ABC)' = A'+B'+C'     (from 2, extending to three terms)
```

so the first and last are the same, and the middle two are the same.

Answer (score 3):

\$\bar A \bar B \bar C \$ does not equal  \$  \bar A+ \bar B + \bar C \$

If you let A=0, B= 1, and C=1

Then \$\bar A \bar B \bar C \$ = 0 and \$  \bar A+ \bar B + \bar C \$ = 1

It's clear that they are not the same

If you apply deMorgan's for \$\bar A \bar B \bar C \$ you would end up with  (A+B+C)'. Which is what you said.

Comment: Thanks, so, is this wrong explanation? http://www.indiabix.com/digital-electronics/boolean-algebra-and-logic-simplification/discussion-138

Comment: The explanation from privithi is correct. He doesn't make the claim that A'B'C' = A'+B'+C' - which is what this question is asking.

Comment: No, the explanation is correct. It's just that the solid bar over ABC means the total expression ABC is inverted, not the individual terms.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  Whose answer is right? What is different between total inverted and individual divided?

Comment: @efox29 Would you make it sure?

Comment: @Carter what ? make what sure ?

Comment: @efox29 the assume that the individual inverted term and totally inverted term is totally different. So I want to your comment about WhatRoughBeast's comment. Would you please help me?

Comment: @Carter the individual inverted and total inverted ARE different. They are NOT the same. What WhatRoughBeast said was that they are different. There is no comment or discussion regarding what he said. What he said was right. The link you provided is ALSO right. The answer I gave is also right. There might be some misunderstanding on your part though - perhaps if you have a specific question or an explanation of what your understand of boolean algebra is, we can clarify some things for you.